# Either drawImage or paintImage doesn't work properly in Flutter

Tags: canvas, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I basically want to show an image that I have in the assets folder onto the canvas.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as ui;

    ...

    ui.Image img = ui.Image.asset("images/some_image.png");
    ui.paintImage(canvas: canvas, image: img);
```

And have got the following error message when I tried to assign img to paintImage's image.

> The argument type 'Image (C:\ABC\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\image.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image (C:\ABC\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\painting.dart)'.

I don't really know what could go wrong, I have seen other codes that had a similar approach with ui.Image.

Please advise.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two classes called `Image` in flutter, in different packages.

There's the [Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html), which behaves like a widget and can be instantiated from an asset, from memory or from the network through its named constructors.

There's also the ui package [Image](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) which is used when painting at a lower level, for example in a `CustomPainter`. Since this version is in the `ui` package it's normally imported with the `ui` prefix like this:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
```

Don't import `material` as `ui`! That will lead to a lot of confusion.

To make a widget, use the `Image.asset` constructor, passing the asset name.

To make a `ui.Image` from an asset use this snippet:

```
  Future<ui.Image> load(String asset) async {
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(asset);
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return fi.image;
  }
```

Comment: Ah, i see.
Thank you

Comment: I came upon this answer now and having a very similar problem. My image is a base64Encoded string so I am trying to do the following:
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    canvas.drawImage(await load(image), Offset(0.0, 0.0), Paint());
...
  Future<ui.Image> load(String image) async {
    Uint8List bytes = base64Decode(image);
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
//    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return fi.image;
  *and getting Unable to load error

Comment: Best to ask a new question.

Comment: @Damandroid did you got the solution for your query above ?

Comment: No @princeoo7. It went on a back burner for now.